# Container Div does not contain the inner div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#a {
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="right">
    <p>This is a Test.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9d8wq0by/

Comment: ok..but what is the problem?

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9d8wq0by/1/) what you want?

Comment: The div with id of right  should appear inside the  "a"

Comment: currently a shows as a line.  Div as a block element should expand to its contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not containing the child because absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. As an alternative, you could float the element to the right, and then add a clearfix to the parent element.

You can also add `box-sizing: border-box` to both of the elements in order to account for the borders and include it in the elements height/width calculations.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gaae0m6g/)

```
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
#a {
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#a, .right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

Alternatively, rather than floating the element to the right, you could also add `margin-left: auto`:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0ou5wxfn/)

```
.right {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9d8wq0by/1/) fiddle

You specified `position:absolute` for `.right` and `position:relative` for `#a` and that is wrong.

Either you have to specify both, the parent and the child to be of the same positioning or, the parent should be absolutely positioned and the child relatively.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d8wq0by/4/)

The updated CSS for `.right` would be as follows

```
.right {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To make the `.right` div stick to the right side, you can just add a `float:right` in the CSS for `.right`.

Comment: does not work for me ,can you please attach fiddle. I want to see the .right DIv inside the other one.

Comment: ran your fiddle, .right Div shows on the  Left not right.

Comment: @SNash How is it? is taht what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

The parent should be `absolute` and the children `relative`. You did the opposite.

The parent can also be `relative`

```css
.right {
    position: relative;
    float: right; //You need this to make the child glue to the right of the parent
    right: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#a
{
 border: 3px solid #73AD21;
 position:  absolute;
 width:100%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a">
<div class="right">
  <p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And for Odin's sake, tell me what was your father's advice.

Comment: I've added `float: right` to the child so it glues to the right side of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

In connection with the above answer, you could use the float: right method, you could add css to clear the float. So the new .right CSS and the clearfix would be:

```
.right {
float:right;
right: 0px;
width: 300px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
padding: 10px;
}

a:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```